# tooltipster not automatic close on hover

Tags: jquery, tooltipster

Have tooltipster in use to show a feedback if the user klicks on a "add to"-button. The tooltipster close automatic after few seconds. Now i need a solution that the automatic close is deactivated if the mouse is over the tooltipster (hover). Is this possible?

My Code:

```
 $('.mgu-ekl-info').tooltipster({
            functionBefore: function(instance, helper){
                $.each($.tooltipster.instances(), function(i, instance){
                    instance.close();
                  });
            },
            contentCloning: true,
            timer: 2500,
            trigger: 'click',
            'maxWidth': 280,
            'minHeight': 280,
            animation: 'grow',
            interactive: true,
            arrow: false,
            distance: -10,
            contentAsHTML: true,
            theme: 'tooltipster-shadow'
        });
```

Thanks for help.

cheers
thomas

Comment: you should make a working snippet including all relevant code ( css html jquery ) so that the problem can be reproduced. that way we can help you better

Comment: Side note: stop using the `contentAsHTML` as it's useless here, read the documentation to know what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this option: `delay: [300, 2500]` and remove `trigger: 'click'`, obviously.